# How to fill the color outside of source in pixmap

Tags: c++, qt

I had tried to fill the color outside of the actual image but fails to do so. I get the pixmap as the input.

```
QRect target = AlignRect(aRect, iPixmap.size(), Alignment());
aPainter.drawPixmap(target, iPixmap);

QPainter painter(&iPixmap);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);

painter.setBrush(QColor::fromRgb(43, 174, 255));
painter.setPen(QColor::fromRgb(43, 174, 255));

painter.drawRect(target);
```

I get the below image as the pixmap.

[image: From]

I want to fill the color outside the white icon like

[image: to this]

Can someone give the pointer for the same?

Comment: draw a rect from 0,0 with W and H of the widgets size

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily because your iPixmap has a transparent background...
You can draw a rect at 0,0 with a WIDTH and HEIGH of the widgets size and then after that place the X on top of that.

example:

```
painter.drawRect(0,0,w,h);
```